# What's the C#-idiomatic way for applying an operator across two lists?

Tags: c#, list

I'm used to doing this (from other languages):

```
 a = 1, 2, 3;
 b = 5, 1, 2;

 c = a * b;  // c = 5, 2, 6
```

This takes two lists of equal size and applies a function to their members, one at a time, to get a list of the results.  It could be a function as simple as multiplication (above) or something more complex:

```
 c = b>a ? b-a : 0;  // c = 4, 0, 0
```

I can think of a few different ways to do this in C#, but I'm not sure how a C#-trained programmer would do it.  What's the proper way of going about this in the C# world?

*(The only part I'm asking about is where* `c = f(a,b)`*.  I'm familiar with creating lists and accessing their elements.)*

Comment: Good question, I would probably just do this with a `for` loop due to the need for parallel indices. For multiplying by a simple scalar, a `Select` statement.

Comment: Look into the ins-and-outs of LINQ for operations such as this, as it provides clean, shorthand notition for selecting, or applying operators to lists. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx

Comment: @VP., write that as an answer, give an example of using LINQ for that purpose, and I'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: See Jon's answer, it has the correct LINQ solution.

Comment: Also consider [Anti-pattern: parallel collections, by Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections.aspx).

Comment: Any use of LINQ will be a **lot** slower then a simple for loop, as there will be a method call for each array item.   So if "*" is fast, don't use LINQ.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, that link is dead, but see [Jon Skeet's blog](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/).

Comment: @Rawling Not sure, but my thinking is that someone with a similar question may already be thinking about linq and hence search on that.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
var c = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => x * y);
```

For the more complex one after your edit:

```
var c = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => x > y ? x - y : 0);
```

Note that `Zip` is an extension method both [from `Enumerable` that acts on `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and from [`Queryable` that acts on `IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd268140%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so it is possible that, should the lambda be one a given query provider can deal with, that it could be processed as a SQL query on a database, or some other way other than in-memory in .NET.

Someone mentioned that this was new with 4.0 in the comments. It's not hard to implement for 3.5 yourself:

```
public class MyExtraLinqyStuff
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
      //Do null checks immediately;
      if(first == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("first");
      if(second == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("second");
      if(resultSelector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("resultSelector");
      return DoZip(first, second, resultSelector);
    }
    private static IEnumerable<TResult> DoZip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
      using(var enF = first.GetEnumerator())
      using(var enS = second.GetEnumerator())
        while(enF.MoveNext() && enS.MoveNext())
          yield return resultSelector(enF.Current, enS.Current);
    }
}
```

For .NET2.0 or .NET3.0 you can have the same, but not as an extension method, which answers another question from the comments; there wasn't really an idiomatic way of doing such things in .NET at that time, or at least not with a firm consensus among those of us coding in .NET then. Some of us had methods like the above in our toolkits (though not extension methods obviously), but that was more that we were influenced by other languages and libraries than anything else (e.g. I was doing things like the above because of stuff I knew from C++'s STL, but that was hardly the only possible source of inspiration)

Comment: Important note, [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is new to .NET 4.0 so if you are targeting 3.5 it will not be available. (but it is not hard to implment yourself as an extension method)

Comment: Couldn't remember quick enough that it was `Zip`. +1

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, That probably explains why I keep forgetting about it... +1 for the easiest and most succinct solution!

Comment: Is there a .NET <4.0 idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: I love `Zip`, but like others I always forget about it. You can get a list of squares for example like this `var ints = Enumerable.Range(1, 5); var squares = ints.Zip(ints, (i, j) => i * j);`

Comment: @DavidG Or `Enumerable.Range(1,5).Select(x => x*x)`

Comment: @Joe not really, but take a quick look at the [soure code for it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#2b8d0f02389aab71),  It would not be hard to add to your own project.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, that's basically what I've already done, writing my own `Zip` function, but going down that road, I end up just remaking APL in C#...

Comment: @Joe, those who do not learn from Linq are doomed to re-implement it. (I'm not sure if that's better or worse than having ones rather ad-hoc but still pretty useful little collection of methods rendered obsolete when 3.5 came out).

Comment: Per one of your last updates about not being able to do extension methods in .NET 2.0 or 3.0, I discovered [a neat trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346554/can-i-use-extension-methods-and-linq-in-net-2-0-or-3-0) a while ago you can do to add support for extension methods to .NET 2.0 or 3.0. However you need to be using Visual Studio 2008 or newer for it to work.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I prefer not to use that trick, and keep 3.0-or-lower acting 3.0-or-lower consistently, though it's a good one to know about for what it shows about how the `ExtensionAttribute` and the extension language feature interact with each other.

Comment: Ah, `Zip`. One of my favorite higher order functions in any language that supports them. Exactly the right choice for this kind of problem.

Comment: It's strange the answers that get the most votes. I'm happy with the answer, but I wouldn't put this anywhere near my top 10.

Answer (score 23):

Assuming .Net 3.5 with lists of equal length:

```
var a = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var b = new List<int>() { 5, 1, 2 }; 
    
var c = a.Select((x, i) => b[i] * x);
```

Result:

> 5
>
> 2
>
> 6

[DotNetFiddle.Net Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DrGrRW)

Comment: Is `Select` a Linq function?

Comment: [System.Linq.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).aspx) is an extension method found in the assembly `System.Core`.

Answer (score 19):

If you are not using .NET 4.0 here is how to write your own extension method to do a Zip.

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, IEnumerable<TSecond> second, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector) 
{
    using (IEnumerator<TFirst> e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<TSecond> e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return resultSelector(e1.Current, e2.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

For .NET verions without LINQ I would recommend a for loop to accomplish this:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>(){4,7,9};
List<int> list2 = new List<int>(){11,2,3};
List<int> newList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; ++i)
{
    newList.Add(Math.Max(list1[i], list2[i]));
}
```

This assumes, of course, the lists are the same size and not changing. If you know the list size ahead of time you could also instantiate it to the correct size then just set the element during the loop.

Comment: Now we have all our bases covered, A post 3.5 solution, a 3.5 solution and a pre 3.5 solution. (for the size issue, you can replicate what Zip does by making the for loop `for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(list1.Count, list2.Count); ++i)`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Which features in your solution aren't available pre-3.5?

Comment: @BenAaronson Extension methods. But you can put extension method support back in via a [neat hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346554/can-i-use-extension-methods-and-linq-in-net-2-0-or-3-0).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Extension methods yes, but what LINQ features do you use?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ah, got it.

Comment: There's no need to restrict to lists for either input or output with 2.0 (or even with 1.0), but more importantly there's no reason to assume `list1.Count <= list2.Count`

Comment: There is a reason to assume `list1.Count == list2.Count`, because thats what the OP Stated: `This takes two lists of equal size and applies a function`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips good .NET code does not assume it's been called correctly, if it's intended for reuse (a private method only called in a limited number of cases is another matter).

Comment: @JonHanna of course it does, I wouldn't disagree.  However, a valid and acceptable answer on *SO* should at a minimum only includes what is needed to answer the question.  This does that per the OPs exact request.

Comment: I'll add that if I were going to place this sample code into my code somewhere, I would at least wrap this in a method, do some length checking, and make the comparison operator a parameter.